# Using xmonad configuaration on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: window-manager, xmonad

I'd like to use [this](https://github.com/vicfryzel/xmonad-config) xmonad configuration on ubuntu 12.04.

I followed the `Installing requirements on Ubuntu Linux` section from the above link and installed dependencies that aren't mentioned: `sudo apt-get install rxvt gnome-panel`.

After logout, I chose `GNOME with Xmonad` and xmonad starts, but it doesn't look the same way as in the link above. For example, `Alt+p` doesn't start `dmenu` and instead of xmonad status bar with numbered workspaces, the usual ubuntu taskbar shows up.

What's the correct way to use the linked configuration on ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

When you pick `GNOME with Xmonad`, you're telling it to run in Gnome. I've never actually tried that myself, but I believe it's actually meant to keep some of the Gnome GUI around. If you want to get rid of that, you need to run xmonad without Gnome. The way I usually do it is by making an `xmonad.desktop` file in `/usr/share/xsessions/` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XMonad
Comment=Lightweight tiling window manager
Exec=xmonad
Icon=xmonad.png
Type=XSession
```

That allows you to pick xmonad from the login screen.